# Pharo Metalink not works on #ifTrue: send node

Tags: pharo

When I add MetaLink to all send nodes in the following code, the Metalink on `#ifTrue:` not works:

```
aMethod
    10 = 11
        ifTrue: [ ^ 3 ]
```

code to add MetaLinks:

```
ast sendNodes do: [ :n | 
            n link: (MetaLink new
                        metaObject: [ :node | 
                            Transcript show: node asString; cr ];
                        arguments: #(node);
                        selector: #value:;
                        control: #before;
                        yourself) ]
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?
How can I add a MetaLink on a `#ifTrue:` send?

Comment: Please explain what does not work as you expected. Note also that the compiler optimizes if messages for the sake of performance, so they are not sent but *inlined*.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I expect my block in Metalink to be executed two times. because there is two send node in the code. How can I disable optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @ LeandroCaniglia, this is because of compile optimization.

You can uncheck `Inline If` in `Opal Compiler settings` and recompile the method.

After recompile, reinstall your Metalinks and you will see `#ifTrue:` as a message call.